# jquery attr alt duplicated into the attr title

Tags: jquery

I wrote this tiny jQuery code piece to get the alt tag value and apply the same value to the same input as the attr title.  This works but not when I put it into my larger jQuery file.  So I'm wondering if I can write this out in one chained jQuery line instead of two.

```
var modname = $("input").attr("alt");
$("input").attr("title",modname);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set the title of all inputs to the value of the alt attribute, you can do this:

```
$('input').attr('title', function(){ return $(this).attr('alt')} );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can chain it (with only one `<input>`), otherwise the **'alt'** attribute from the first found `<input>` would be assign to all the other `<input>`'s in your DOM

```
$('input').attr('title', $('input').attr('alt'));
```

Better, if you got more than one `<input>`, do it with `.each()` *(it also works if you only got one `<input>`, it's just cleaner)*

```
$("input").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("title", $(this).attr("alt"));
});
```

[Like in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SJUDy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
$("input").attr("title", $("input").attr("alt"));
```

Comment: but only if there is only one input in the page.

Comment: True dat. I though he was using input here as a placeholder.

Comment: Yeah - given what the OP wrote it looks like he has only one input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').attr('title', function(index, item) { return $(item).attr('alt') });
```